# Lifecycle (starting, shutting down) of a ScheduledExecutorService inside a Spring Signleton

Tags: spring, executorservice, applicationcontext, application-shutdown

I'm using a `ScheduledExecutorService` inside a Spring Singleton. It executes a periodical check that's scheduled to run every x minutes. I'm lazily (or half-lazily) initializing the Singleton member variables (the Executor) by implementing a `ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>#onApplicationEvent`method - that created the `ScheduledExecutorService` and assigns a task.

I need to deal with the shutdown of the `ExecutorService`, and wonder how to do that properly. I do know that Spring has it's context shutdown process, and wonder whether it's reasonable to call the shutdown somewhere from there.

What exactly happens if the `ExecutorService` doesn't get shutdown, and the Server is being closed or terminated? Doesn't the JVM just clears all memory related to this program?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented a "shutdown"/"destroy" method according to the documentation. I still can't figure out on which scenario Spring performs such a shutdown process. If I'm just stopping the web server, the method doesn't get called.

Comment: Why are you doing the scheduling yourself instead of using `@EnableScheduling` with an `@Scheduled` annotation. This way Spring will manage the executor for you. Also how are you shutting down the server, nicely or by doing a `kill`?